# Bash script: two consecutive calls to curl, just one is executed

Tags: bash, curl, http-post

I have a bash script containing, among other things, two consecutive calls to curl, like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# Stuff...

curl -X POST -d "data=<some_post_data>" http://url/to/rest/api

curl -X POST -d "data=<more_post_data>" http://url/to/rest/api

# More stuff
```

My problem is **just call 1 does something**. First call, takes about **10 mins** to complete:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   712    0   419    0   293      0      0 --:--:--  0:10:05 --:--:--    28
```

But the second one, ends in just 3 seconds:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100    51  100   133     15     41  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--    41
```

Looking at backend logs (I mean, the endpoints being called) looks like the second call never reach its target. I've tried with a sleep of 30 secs between two calls. No effect.

Strange thing is if I comment the first call, the second one is just called normally (takes about 6 mins)

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   192    0    59    0   133      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:47 --:--:--     0
```

For the big picture: I really have a sequence of several curl calls (more than 2), but the problem is between these 2 calls. Until then, all the previous calls run normally.

Any ideas about what's happening?

Comment: what's different about the two data blocks? size? one is "calculate pi to the 10 trillionth place" and the other is "do 1+1"?

Comment: What does it have to do with `bash`?

Comment: Both are just SQL INSERT calls: INSERT INTO table SELECT values from other_table. The endpoint just gets this SQL calls and runs them into a database. I'm trying with GET instead of POST now.

Comment: What `curl -I` returns ?? - I don't know how your backend works but I suppouse you can get some 5xx status code (500, 502, 503 or 504) after first bunch of INSERT's.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for your last suggestion. It helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was unrelated with cURL. Basically, the backend cache the results before sending them to the actual datastore. So, the second cURL didn't find the data the first one stored (they were connected, really, I realized later). I fixed it by putting a sleep between both calls. So, the cache system has enough time to dump the data.